# Not able log in to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, login

I have just upgraded my ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. Now I have the problem with logging in.Once I type the password and press ENTER it comes back to the old page and asks me to log in again. I've tried many solutions given in several sites but still those commands didn't work.
I tried downloading genome. In that env also it's not possible for me to log in.

And now there is one more problem. Can't use the sudo command on terminal. And I don't know how to recover all the data stored in the laptop. I think this is the best time to say goodbye to Ubuntu and its problems.

Is there anything which I can do to solve thus problem?

Comment: You should edit your question to list what you have tried to avoid everyone from duplicating your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to enter recovery mode (from grub), get into root

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

After running the above commands, the shell should be remounted with read/write permission. Now you can run limited sets of commends, including password change commands as the root user.

To change or reset your forgotten password, run the commands below.

```
sudo passwd username
```

Replace username with your account name or user name for the machine. If you have to root account enabled, you should replace username with root to change the root password.

When you run the above commands, you’ll be prompted to create and confirm a password for the account name you mentioned. create it and you’re done.

When you’re done, type reboot to restart your machine. This is how to reset your password on Ubuntu.

all credits to liberiangeek.net

[detailed Description and Original Article here](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/10/change-forgotten-password-ubuntu-14-04-servers/)

Enjoy!

Comment: The problem is not with the forgotten password. The login page flashes every time I  give the correct password. If I  enter the wrong password it says that the password is wrong. I just want to log in to the Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: might be a problem with lightdm, http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop